# Scroll/active script and anchor positioning

Tags: jquery, html, css

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/W3Ee9/4/)**

```
var lastId,
```

^Just to meet post requirements, since i don't really have a code problem .

The active tag is supposed to only highlight the section being viewed, the script usually works perfectly fine so I don't know what's wrong.

Also please let me know why the anchors are offset and how i can position the anchors properly, possibly without moving the divs.

Edit: As you can see the active tag doesnt apply properly as you scroll and if you click the links you can also see the anchors are offset.

Comment: Give more explanation pertaining the fiddle. It's not clear as to what you think is wrong here ..

Answer (score 0):

I'll do my best to try to help, but your question is not very specific.

I'll assume that your question is about the css and layout (based on your sentence that starts "Also please...").

I've changed the HTML and CSS a bit.

HTML

```
<div id="nav">
    <div>
      <a href="#number1">number 1</a>
    </div>
  <a href="#number2">number 2</a><br>
  <a href="#number3">number 3</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#nav div {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #0F0;
}
```

The "numbers" all seem to line up in the center.

Is this what you're looking for?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W3Ee9/5/)